# Confidence Intervals using Normal Distribution with variance known

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

From a sample of $32$ observations from a population with $σ^2$
 $= 24.602$, we obtained $x = 79.47$. Construct a $99$% confidence interval for $\mu$.

$(a) 79.47±1.4424$
**(b) 79.47±1.7186**
$(c) 79.47±2.0430$
$(d) 79.47±2.2622$

Why is the bolded (b) the answer? I keep getting (d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R

```
 n = 32
 sigma = 4.96
 SE = sigma/sqrt(n)
 ME = qnorm(.995)*SE
 x = 79.47
 x+c(-ME,ME)
```

=($77.21, 81.73$)
**Answer D**

Is it possible the book made an error??

**With some further explanation, I am certain the book made an error**

Here is what the book used. They used a 95% confidence interval

```
 n = 32
 sigma = 4.96
 SE = sigma/sqrt(n)
 ME = qnorm(.975)*SE
 x = 79.47
 x+c(-ME,ME)
```

= ($77.75, 81.19$)

You were right, the answer is in fact D. Hopefully the code isn't overwhelming, I could have done the same process by hand, but the book used z = 1.96 for a 95% confidence interval, rather than using 2.58 for a 99% confidence interval

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I feel less stupid now haha!

Comment: @EconDude You're welcome. Sorry I had commented a few times and deleted those because I thought there was an issue, but everything is all good.

Answer (score 2):

Respectively, answers (A) through (D) correspond to symmetric two-sided $90\%$, $95\%$, $98\%$, and $99\%$ confidence intervals.  The critical values for each are:

(A) $1.64485$, (B) $1.95996$, (C) $2.32635$, (D) $2.57583$,

with standard errors being $\sqrt{24.602/32} \approx 0.87682$.  Thus the respective margins of error are ($\pm$)

(A) $1.44224$, (B) $1.71853$, (C) $2.03979$, (D) $2.25854$.